# set + nth element : fast implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

For the following data structure:

- add an element in O(lg(n))
- remove an element in O(lg(n))
- find the k'th element in O(lg(n))

we can use a balanced BST which each node has size of it's subtree, but it needs to implement red-black tree which is not fast to code.

any better solution?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist

Answer (score 7):

The general type of structure you are looking for is qualified with *Indexed* or *Indexable*, that is a structure augmented with count to be able to access elements by indexes.

You could use either:

- an Indexed Tree: [Binary Search Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) ([Red-Black Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree), [AVL Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avl_tree)), [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), [Finger-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree), ...
- an Indexed [Skip-List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

*(and perhaps a few others :p)*

I tend to think that Skip-Lists are easier to implement than BST, as you can use a randomized height instead of all the balancing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to implement your own augmented O(log(n)) data structure that allows rank based inserts/lookups. A balanced BST, skip list, or some modified segment tree or Binary Indexed Tree should work.

In Java you can also use [TreeList](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.html) from Apache Commons.

If k is fixed and you are using C++, you can use a clever trick you can find at [TopCoder](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=match_editorials&d2=srm310) (Scroll down to the section titled "Floating Median"). Bascially you use 2 `std::multiset`s, one for the first k elements and another for the last N-k elements. Every time you add/remove something, you update the multisets accordingly. Getting the kth element is simply looking up the last element in the first multiset.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [AA Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_tree) are easier to implement than RBTs but otherwise are pretty much equivalent to them.

Comment: Nice structure, I didn't know of it. I really like how the author managed to reduce down the number of special cases and maintenance operations!

Answer (score 0):

You could give a shot to [skip lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) with a randomized node height. It should be able to do what you want.

It's a randomized data structure. As an idea is very clean and it's relatively easy to implement. Red-black tries have many special cases. Skip lists have no special cases and are easy to get right. In addition they behave very well in practice - the constant in O() is rather small.